# ASUS H81M-E - DVI display does not work at bootup or in the bios, but works fine in windows

Tags: boot, motherboard, dvi

I just put together a new system built around an ASUS H81M-E motherboard. The bare essential setup has a zalman 500W PSU, H81M-E, intel i5-4440 and corsair 1600 1x8GB DIMM.

I connected my monitor using DVI to the onboard DVI connector and to my horror I didn't see the bios/boot screen when I powered it on. Instead I got the message: "The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display".

After the usual debugging, reseating the RAM etc giving no joy, I found a VGA cable and voila - I can see the boot screen and get into the bios etc.

I installed windows 7 professional 64bit and installed all the latest chipset drivers and intel graphics drivers. I also upgraded the bios to version 0808, the latest (built on 6th Jan 2014).

After all that, the DVI still does not work on boot or in the bios, but it does work perfectly when windows has finished booting.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this before? I have reported the problem to ASUS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another monitor and it works fine on the DVI, even at boot and in the bios. So it must be something strange with the first monitor.